# Network preferences will not open

Tags: airport, login, system-settings

All network preferences are frozen on my macbook. This problem happens when I do the following:

1. Fast User switching is on.
2. At least two users are logged into the system.
3. I've switched from one wifi network to another.

When this happens, Airport appears to hang. The airport icon in the menu bar runs through its "searching" animation forever, and airport cannot be turned off. If I attempt to access network preferences from the system preferences it hangs and won't respond.

The only console message that appears is when I force quit the process opening system preferences:

```
([0x0-0x180180].com.apple.systempreferences[3599]) Exited: Terminated: 15
```

I also can't open the Activity Monitor.

I cannot switch users, and if I log out the user I'm in I'll lose a lot of work (I'm running a long simulation that is not complete), and also, in the past this has not helped. How can I force airport to die?

Things that do not work include killing processes with the word "airport" in their name.

OS: 10.7.4
Hardware: MacBook Pro i7
`kernel.log`:

```
Jul 11 08:02:37 JD6944 kernel[0]: hibernate_write_image done(0)

Jul 11 08:02:37 JD6944 kernel[0]: sleep

Jul 11 08:02:37 JD6944 kernel[0]: SMC::smcHandleInterruptEvent WARNING status=0x0 (0x40 not set) notif=0x0

Jul 11 09:02:01 JD6944 kernel[0]: Wake reason: EC.LidOpen (User)

Jul 11 09:02:01 JD6944 kernel[0]: SMC::smcHandleInterruptEvent WARNING status=0x0 (0x40 not set) notif=0x0

Jul 11 09:02:01 JD6944 kernel[0]: RTC: PowerByCalendarDate setting ignored

Jul 11 09:02:05 JD6944 kernel[0]: Previous Sleep Cause: 5

Jul 11 09:02:05 JD6944 kernel[0]: SMC::smcHandleInterruptEvent WARNING status=0x0 (0x40 not set) notif=0x0

Jul 11 09:02:06 JD6944 kernel[0]: en1: 802.11d country code set to 'US'.

Jul 11 09:02:06 JD6944 kernel[0]: en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165

Jul 11 09:02:13 JD6944 kernel[0]: AppleThunderboltNHI::enablePower - turn power off, status = 0x0, result_value = 0x0

Jul 11 09:06:42 JD6944 kernel[0]: (default pager): [KERNEL]: default_pager_backing_store_monitor - send LO_WAT_ALERT

Jul 11 09:07:04 JD6944 kernel[0]: macx_swapoff SUCCESS

Jul 11 09:07:15 JD6944 kernel[0]: (default pager): [KERNEL]: default_pager_backing_store_monitor - send LO_WAT_ALERT

Jul 11 09:08:00 JD6944 kernel[0]: macx_swapoff SUCCESS

Jul 11 09:23:43 JD6944 kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=3505[GoogleSoftwareUp] clearing CS_VALID

Jul 11 09:57:21 JD6944 kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=3549[GoogleSoftwareUp] clearing CS_VALID
```

System Preferences Hang Log:

```
Date/Time:       2012-07-11 09:05:57 -0400 OS Version:      10.7.4 (Build 11E53) Architecture:    x86_64 Report Version:  9

Command:         System Preferences Path:            /Applications/System Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System Preferences Version:         11.0 (11.0) Build Version:   2 Project Name:    SystemPrefsApp Source Version:  214009000000000 Parent:          launchd [235]

PID:             3413 Event:           hang Duration:        1.12s Steps:           12 (100ms sampling interval)

Pageins:         5 Pageouts:        0


Process:         System Preferences [3413] Path:            /Applications/System Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System Preferences Architecture:    x86_64 UID:             501

  Thread 0x326bf      DispatchQueue 1   User stack:
    12 ??? (in System Preferences) [0x107729b30]
      12 NSApplicationMain + 867 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82cf0244]
        12 -[NSApplication run] + 470 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82a74071]
          12 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82a77735]
            12 _DPSNextEvent + 1247 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82a7807d]
              12 AEProcessAppleEvent + 102 (in HIToolbox) [0x7fff81e7ad7d]
                12 aeProcessAppleEvent + 250 (in AE) [0x7fff8800e9f7]
                  12 _ZL25dispatchEventAndSendReplyPK6AEDescPS_ + 38 (in AE) [0x7fff8800eb03]
                    12 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 200 (in AE) [0x7fff8800ec25]
                      12 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 105 (in Foundation) [0x7fff88f135dc]
                        12 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 283 (in Foundation) [0x7fff88f1374e]
                          12 __-[NSAppleEventManager setEventHandler:andSelector:forEventClass:andEventID:]_block_invoke_1
+ 101 (in Foundation) [0x7fff88f147c7]
                            12 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 65 (in CoreFoundation) [0x7fff8788c541]
                              12 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 307 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82a7ac5a]
                                12 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:] + 272 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82cb9f33]
                                  12 -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:registeringAsReady:completionHandler:]
+ 287 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82a7b10f]
                                    12 -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsWithCompletionHandler:] + 725 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82a7b676]
                                      12 __-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 111 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82a7ba21]
                                        12 __-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:]_block_invoke_1 + 1356 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82d31709]
                                          12 -[NSApplication _doOpenFile:ok:tryTemp:] + 369 (in AppKit) [0x7fff82d2c30d]
                                            12 ??? (in System Preferences) [0x10773b6ba]
                                              12 ??? (in System Preferences) [0x1077306fc]
                                                12 -[NSPrefPaneBundle instantiatePrefPaneObject] + 438 (in PreferencePanes) [0x7fff811f3954]
                                                  12 -[NSPreferencePane loadMainView] + 216 (in PreferencePanes) [0x7fff811f2a42]
                                                    12 ??? (in Network) [0x10ba537d1]
                                                      12 -[NSAdminPreference(Private) mainViewDidLoad] + 321 (in PreferencePanes) [0x7fff811f82e7]
                                                        12 +[SFAuthorization authorization] + 48 (in SecurityFoundation) [0x7fff81b3147f]
                                                          12 -[SFAuthorization initWithFlags:rights:environment:] + 89 (in SecurityFoundation) [0x7fff81b3177c]
                                                            12 AuthorizationCreate + 60 (in Security) [0x7fff85123f8c]
                                                              12 Security::SecurityServer::ClientSession::authCreate(AuthorizationItemSet const*, AuthorizationItemSet const*, unsigned int, Security::SecurityServer::AuthorizationBlob&) + 129 (in Security) [0x7fff8512fe21]
                                                                12 Security::SecurityServer::ClientSession::activate() + 139 (in Security) [0x7fff84fe5dc9]
                                                                  12 Security::ModuleNexus<Security::SecurityServer::ClientSession::Global>::operator()()
+ 71 (in Security) [0x7fff84fe5fed]
                                                                    12 Security::ModuleNexusCommon::create(void* (*)()) + 166 (in Security) [0x7fff84fca574]
                                                                      12 Security::ModuleNexus<Security::SecurityServer::ClientSession::Global>::make()
+ 28 (in Security) [0x7fff85032537]
                                                                        12 Security::SecurityServer::ClientSession::Global::Global() + 267 (in Security) [0x7fff8503265d]
                                                                          12 ucsp_client_setup + 257 (in Security) [0x7fff85032c91]
                                                                            12 mach_msg_trap + 10 (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff8444467a]   Kernel stack:
    12 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 (in mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000215930]

  Thread 0x326c5      DispatchQueue 2   User stack:
    12 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54 (in libdispatch.dylib) [0x7fff87d3f31a]
      12 kevent + 10 (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff844467e6]   Kernel stack:
    12 kqueue_scan + 416 (in mach_kernel) [0xffffff800053a660]

  Thread 0x326c4      DispatchQueue 12   User stack:
    12 start_wqthread + 13 (in libsystem_c.dylib) [0x7fff855a2b85]
      12 _pthread_wqthread + 316 (in libsystem_c.dylib) [0x7fff855a13da]
        12 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 198 (in libdispatch.dylib) [0x7fff87d3f92c]
          12 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 54 (in libdispatch.dylib) [0x7fff87d40132]
            12 _dispatch_queue_drain + 264 (in libdispatch.dylib) [0x7fff87d402d6]
              12 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18 (in libdispatch.dylib) [0x7fff87d3ea86]
                12 __auto_zone_collect_block_invoke_0 + 74 (in libauto.dylib) [0x7fff853b721a]
                  12 auto_collect_internal(Auto::Zone*, unsigned int) + 459 (in libauto.dylib) [0x7fff853bb7db]
                    12 Auto::Zone::invalidate_garbage(unsigned long, void**) + 73 (in libauto.dylib) [0x7fff853ce019]
                      12 batchFinalizeOnTwoThreads + 264 (in libobjc.A.dylib) [0x7fff872f86a8]
                        12 __psynch_cvwait + 10 (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff84445bca]   Kernel stack:
    12 psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (in mach_kernel) [0xffffff800059daa0]

  Binary Images:
         0x107728000 -        0x10774afff  com.apple.systempreferences 11.0 (11.0) <586F487B-3019-32FC-9BCD-44A604A7178C> /Applications/System Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System Preferences
         0x10ba51000 -        0x10bae1ff7  com.apple.preference.network 2.6.1 (2.6.1) <B3F96860-141A-3D39-B2CF-153210D7E88F> /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Network.prefPane/Contents/MacOS/Network
      0x7fff811ef000 -     0x7fff8120bfff  com.apple.frameworks.preferencepanes 15.0 (15.0) <A1ABA9DB-2C8A-3C96-976A-21E63194F7B2> /System/Library/Frameworks/PreferencePanes.framework/Versions/A/PreferencePanes
      0x7fff81b30000 -     0x7fff81bd2fff  com.apple.securityfoundation 5.0 (55116) <A9311EF6-B7F7-3DA5-84E8-21BC9B2C3C69> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
      0x7fff81e6a000 -     0x7fff82196ff7  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.9 (???) <B7D2A06B-7BE5-3355-BF7D-8139100B9B97> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
      0x7fff82a6f000 -     0x7fff83675ff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.7.3 (1138.47) <CAF5783F-F80B-30E7-929F-BBA6D96C5C44> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
      0x7fff8442f000 -     0x7fff8444ffff  libsystem_kernel.dylib ??? (???) <1DDC0B0F-DB2A-34D6-895D-E5B2B5618946> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
      0x7fff84fc9000 -     0x7fff852b2ff7  com.apple.security 7.0 (55148.1) <E9C46204-1336-3D90-BC67-5162FC7079D2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
      0x7fff853b6000 -     0x7fff85404fff  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <D8AC8458-DDD0-3939-8B96-B6CED81613EF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
      0x7fff85551000 -     0x7fff8562efef  libsystem_c.dylib ??? (???) <41B43515-2806-3FBC-ACF1-A16F35B7E290> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
      0x7fff872e3000 -     0x7fff873c7e5f  libobjc.A.dylib ??? (???) <871E688B-CF57-3BC7-80D6-F6476DFF109B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
      0x7fff877f6000 -     0x7fff879caff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.7.2 (635.21) <62A3402E-A4E7-391F-AD20-1EF20236CE1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
      0x7fff87d3d000 -     0x7fff87d4bfff  libdispatch.dylib ??? (???) <1D5BE322-A9B9-3BCE-8FAC-076FB07CF54A> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
      0x7fff8800b000 -     0x7fff8804afff  com.apple.AE 527.7 (527.7) <B82F7ABC-AC8B-3507-B029-969DD5CA813D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
      0x7fff88edb000 -     0x7fff891f4fff  com.apple.Foundation 6.7.2 (833.25) <22AAC369-B63C-3C55-8AC6-C3ECBA44DA7B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
```

Comment: what does console says when you try to open it?
check the logs for any kind of errors and repost.
console = /applications/utilities/console

Comment: @pjj console, as mentioned, has no data at all beyond the exit message when system preferences is force quit.

Comment: Can you, as an admin user, go to `/var/log` and have a look at kernel.log and system.log?

Comment: @patrix yes. The var/log/system.log points me to a hang log for System Preferences. That file is 6800 lines long, so possibly a bit much to upload. What parts in particular would be helpful?

Comment: The point in time where the error first occurs (which is, if I understand your question correctly, the moment you switch WiFi networks).

Comment: @patrix added to the question.

Comment: That's the crash log, not the extract from system/kernel.log. And to analyze further we need the logs from around the time the problem started, not from force quitting Preferences.

Comment: @patrix added the kernel log.

Answer (score 3):

> Q: "How can I force airport to die?"

You can disable Wi-Fi (aka "AirPort") by using the `networksetup` command.

In order to do this, you have to know which "en" port AirPort is using. *Usually* it is either en0 or en1. You can find out for sure by using this command:

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder
```

and looking at the output.

For example, here is the output of that command on my MacBook Air:

```
An asterisk (*) denotes that a network service is disabled.
(1) Bluetooth DUN
(Hardware Port: Bluetooth DUN, Device: Bluetooth-Modem)

(2) USB Ethernet
(Hardware Port: USB Ethernet, Device: en2)

(3) Wi-Fi
(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: en0)

(4) Bluetooth PAN
(Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN, Device: en1)
```

As you can see in the third entry, mine is 'en0'. Therefore, to turn off Wi-Fi on my Mac, I use the command:

```
sudo networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```

turning it back on again, as you might expect:

```
sudo networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

*Note that I am on 10.9 and so things may be slightly different, but I do not think they will be significant. At one point Mac OS X's `networksetup` command may have referred to this as "AirPort" instead of "Wi-Fi" but I think that was back in Snow Leopard (10.6).*